# Where in the standard does it say that when you do bitwise operations, it will behave like big-endian?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Regardless of endianness, bitshifting and other operations always behave as if they are big-endian. So small numbers are on the right, and big ones are on the left. Also the bit for signedness is on the left.

My question is where does it explicitly say that this is like this? My copy of the C11 draft doesn't even mention endianness, and in the bitwise part there is some math expressions that I don't understand, so I'm not sure where this part is.

Comment: You are mistaken.  Endianness is only an issue when you break a machine word up into bytes and read/write them to a disk file, in an order.  When that machine word is in memory, it is what it is.  The most-significant bit is the most-significant bit, and the least-significant bit is the least-significant bit.  You can't even say which of the bits is on the "right" or the "left".  (The most-significant bits only *seem* to be on the left if your version of `printf` happens to print them that way using `%x` — as, indeed, most versions of `printf` do. :-) )

Comment: In other words, it's not that C is big-endian — it's more like, the world's left-to-right languages are big-endian!

Comment: Numbers are written to a console in Western languages with the most significant digit to the left.  This is completely independent of whether the words are stored big-endian or little-endian internally.

Comment: *the bitwise part there is some math expressions* Right.  That's what I meant by "when that machine word is in memory, it is what it is".  Computer arithmetic is generally (and in C is definitely) defined in accordance with the laws of mathematics, not based on how we might print some digits on paper.  Any digits we print on paper are just another external representation of an underlying *number*.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this is that the terms "big-endian" and "little-endian" refer to how *bytes* are laid out in memory or on disk.  But terms like "left shift" and "right shift" and "MSB" and "LSB" refer to the *bits* in a *word*, and that word is best thought of as a single, monolithic entity.

Comment: But I was mistaken, too.  I said "Endianness is only an issue when you break a machine word up into bytes and read/write them to a disk file, in an order. When that machine word is in memory, it is what it is", but that's not quite right.  A more accurate statement would be "Endianness is only an issue when you break a machine word up into bytes and read/write them to memory or a disk file, in an order. When that machine word is in a CPU register so you can do arithmetic on it, it is what it is."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows directly from the description of the bitwise shift operators that the result does not depend on how integers are stored.

The C11 Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
> bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
> the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and
> nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type,
> then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.
>
> 5 The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1
> has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative
> value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
> E1 / 2E2. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting
> value is implementation-defined.

Otherwise there would be a note in the C Standard relative to the way  integers are stored in memory.

Answer (score 10):

> Regardless of endianness, bitshifting and other operations always behave as if they are big-endian.

No, they do not. “Endian” refers to how the bytes (or sometimes bits) of an object are stored in memory. The bit-shift and bit-wise operators, as specified in the C standard, operate on values without regard to how they are stored in memory, so endianness is not involved.

The shift operators associate greater position values with leftward bits and lesser position values with rightward bits by their common names (“left shift” and “right shift”) and some of the terminology in their specifications in the C standard, but this convention refers solely to how humans write binary numerals. It has no effect on how the representations of the values are written to memory.

For example, consider `unsigned int x = 1u << 24;`, using a 32-bit `unsigned int`. The 1 will be left-shifted, producing the value 2<sup>24</sup>, which may be written as 00000001000000000000000000000000 in binary. When written to memory, the C implementation might store the bytes in the order 1, 0, 0, 0 (for a big-endian order) or 0, 0, 0, 1 (for a little-endian order). This order in memory is unrelated to the value, which remains 00000001000000000000000000000000<sub>2</sub> in any conforming C implementation with `unsigned int` of 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

> Where in the standard does it say that when you do bitwise operations, it will behave like big-endian?

As [@Eric observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76156179/2402272), that is a mischaracterization of C behavior.  Bitwise (and substantially all other) operations are defined in terms of the *values* of the operands, not their *representations* in memory.  The bitwise shift operators are a bit special, however, in that these in fact highlight the difference.

As for where this is defined, it is, naturally, defined in the sections that specify the behavior of these operators.  For the bitwise shift operators in particular, this is primarily C23 paragraphs 6.5.7/4-5 (and practically identical text in earlier versions of the language spec).  Relevant excerpts:

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions;
> vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the
> value of the result is `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup>, wrapped around. [...]
>
> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If
> E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative
> value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
> `E1` / 2<sup>`E2`</sup>. [...]

Note that the results are defined arithmetically, not based on storage layout.

Answer (score 1):

C11 has the following to say e.g. for left shifts under `6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators`:

> The result of E1 << E2 is [...] E1 x 2 <sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type [...]

This definition applies regardless of the endianness of the machine,
because it is discribed in terms of the semantic **value**
resulting from the operation, not it's internal **representation** (endianness).

For example, if you were to execute a loop over the resulting value, how many iterations would said loop run? This has nothing to do with the way that the target architecture decides to lay out the value internally.

"left" and "right" shift are really just the conventional name of these operations used because they are intuitive when writing the number in
arabic numeral fashion (most significant digit left).

Even on architectures that use neither little nor big endian ([they exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian)), the operation would still be called left-shift. The definition in the C standard is entirely architecture agnostic.

Comment: Fun fact: the PDP-11 was a very important machine for the early development of C and Unix, and its 32-bit integers were stored in a middle-endian format that indeed has the least-significant byte in the middle.  Probably most of the engineers who might take offense at calling that "really stupid" are not paying attention, but you should be more careful with your words.  Nevertheless, yes, the operation was indeed still called "left shift", and its result was a function of operand values, not storage order.  Machines using that format were in production use at least into the 1990s.

Comment: @John Bollinger: Thank you for that interesting fact! I meant no disrespect, I simply couldn't imagine a valid usecase for this, but I guess it makes sense as an extension to a 16 bit machine. Will edit.